# Spring RequestBody convert JSON to String

Tags: java, spring, rest, deserialization

I have a RestController class which has a method to search for a Film by its title:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/film", method = RequestMethod.POST,
               consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Film getFilm(@RequestBody String filmSearch){
    FilmInfo filmInfo = new FilmInfo();
    Film film = filmInfo.getFilm(filmSearch);
    return film;
}
```

If I send a json String

```
{
 "filmSearch":"<title>"
}
```

to the endpoint from Postman I receive a blank response back.

I then did a

```
System.out.println(filmSearch)
```

right after entering the method to find the String filmSearch was exactly the JSON string I sent from Postman. My application is not seeing the JSON and extracting the value from filmSearch in my request to attach to the in-app String filmSearch.

If I remove the

```
consumes = "application/json"
```

part in the RequestMapping and send over a plain text string of the title it works and I get a Film object sent back as JSON.

I'd rather not use plain text in my search term though, how can I correctly have my JSON be converted into a String on entering the method?

Comment: why do you use a POST HTTP method to retrieve something ?

Comment: I suppose the client side doesn't specify `application/json`  in its request.

Comment: My Postman request is a raw body request with the application/json option selected and not text(plain/text).

Comment: It seems you expect Spring to parse the JSON as an object, see it has a filmSearch attribute, extract its value, and pass this value to your method. Why would it do that? It won't. You send JSON, you receive JSON. It can, however, parse JSON and give you back an object (using a JSON mapper such as Jackson) that matches the structure of the JSON you send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add request body is **String** not Object. Server received is String json not OBJECT. You can try code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/film", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Film getFilm(@RequestParam("search") String search){
    FilmInfo filmInfo = new FilmInfo();
    Film film = filmInfo.getFilm(search);
    return film;
}
```

If you user postman:

- URL: /flim?search=minion
- Method: GET
- Header: Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Okay, I was mistaken in how it worked. I shall implement this instead. Thank you

Comment: Setting a content type header for a GET request is useless: a GET request doesn't have a content.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're passing the entire JSON payload as a string inside the 'getfilm()' function.
What you're expecting to call is `getfilm(<title>)`, but you're actually calling is `getfilm({"filmSearch":"<title>"} )`, which is wrong.
The best choice would be, convert that string to JSON, say like this

```
JSONObject jsonstring = new JSONObject(filmSearch);
FilmInfo filmInfo = new FilmInfo();
Film film = filmInfo.getFilm(jsonstring.get("title"));
```

you can also ignore the 'consumes = "application/json"' from the request mapping.